# PHP array_replace on special condition (advanced transliteration)

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to edit a transliteration function to meet a special condition. I am using a Russian into Latin transliteration that I have adapted for Bulgarian, but there is the special condition that if the letter "я", normally transliterated as "ya", is found at the end of a word, and if preceded by the letter "и", it is transliterated as "a".

Example: without the special condition, "мистерия" is transliterated as "misteriya", whereas the correct transliteration (according to the Bulgarian Law on Transliteration) is "misteria".

What I've tried:

1. Split the source string into words.
2. Check if the word is longer than 2 characters.
3. Check if the last letter is "я".
4. Check if the letter before it is "и".
5. If all of the above conditions are met, replace the values for "я" and "Я" (lowercase and uppercase) in the conversion chart array with their new values.
6. Concatenate all converted words into a string and output it.
7. It doesn't work.

   ```
   function transliterator($string) {
   $converter = array(
   'а' => 'a',   'б' => 'b',   'в' => 'v',
   'г' => 'g',   'д' => 'd',   'е' => 'e',
   'ж' => 'zh',  'з' => 'z',   'и' => 'i',
   'й' => 'y',   'к' => 'k',   'л' => 'l',
   'м' => 'm',   'н' => 'n',   'о' => 'o',
   'п' => 'p',   'р' => 'r',   'с' => 's',
   'т' => 't',   'у' => 'u',   'ф' => 'f',
   'х' => 'h',   'ц' => 'ts',  'ч' => 'ch',
   'ш' => 'sh',  'щ' => 'sht', 'ь' => '',
   'ъ' => 'a',   'ю' => 'yu',  'я' => 'ya',

   'А' => 'A',   'Б' => 'B',   'В' => 'V',
   'Г' => 'G',   'Д' => 'D',   'Е' => 'E',
   'Ж' => 'Zh',  'З' => 'Z',   'И' => 'I',   
   'Й' => 'Y',   'К' => 'K',   'Л' => 'L',   
   'М' => 'M',   'Н' => 'N',   'О' => 'O',   
   'П' => 'P',   'Р' => 'R',   'С' => 'S',   
   'Т' => 'T',   'У' => 'U',   'Ф' => 'F',
   'Х' => 'H',   'Ц' => 'Ts',  'Ч' => 'Ch',
   'Ш' => 'Sh',  'Щ' => 'Sht', 'Ь' => '',
   'Ъ' => 'A',   'Ю' => 'Yu',  'Я' => 'Ya',
   );

   $words = explode(" ", $string);
   $trans_string = "";
   foreach($words as $word) {

   if((strlen($word > 2)) && (strpos($word, "я", -1)) && (strpos($word, "и", -2))) {
       $amend = array("я" => "a", "Я" => "A");
       $converter = array_replace($converter, $amend);
   }
   $trans_word = strtr($word, $converter);
   $trans_string .= $trans_word." ";

   }
   return $trans_string;
   }
   ```

Some help please?

Comment: show the input `$string` contents

Comment: I would use `substr($word, -2) == 'ия'` instead of `strpos`. couldn't get it to work though due to character set probably.

Comment: It is not the array_merge that is not working, it is the if condition

Comment: @RST: I've tried this as well, just tried it again, doesn't work. And yes, the `array_replace` works when taken outside the `if`.

Comment: what is input string $string ? show here

Comment: @JYoThI: It can be any Bulgarian text. Here's a sample: "Здравейте, в деня за размисъл! Все едно в Италия няма нито едно братоубийство и измама. Това е пълна мистерия."
Here, the words "Италия" and "мистерия" should be transliterated to "Italia" and "misteria", but instead they are transliterated to "Italiya" and "misteriya".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `strpos` and `strtr` do not offer multibyte support. For `strpos` you could fix this by using `mb_strpos` or even better rewrite the condition as `(mb_subtr($word, -2) == 'ия')`.

Still, you'll have problems with the rest of the function. I would suggest to use `preg_replace_callback` instead; with the `/u` modifier you'll have multibyte support:

```
function transliterator($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/ия\b|./uis', function ($c) {
        $converter = array(
        'а' => 'a',   'б' => 'b',   'в' => 'v',
        'г' => 'g',   'д' => 'd',   'е' => 'e',
        'ж' => 'zh',  'з' => 'z',   'и' => 'i',
        'й' => 'y',   'к' => 'k',   'л' => 'l',
        'м' => 'm',   'н' => 'n',   'о' => 'o',
        'п' => 'p',   'р' => 'r',   'с' => 's',
        'т' => 't',   'у' => 'u',   'ф' => 'f',
        'х' => 'h',   'ц' => 'ts',  'ч' => 'ch',
        'ш' => 'sh',  'щ' => 'sht', 'ь' => '',
        'ъ' => 'a',   'ю' => 'yu',  'я' => 'ya',

        'А' => 'A',   'Б' => 'B',   'В' => 'V',
        'Г' => 'G',   'Д' => 'D',   'Е' => 'E',
        'Ж' => 'Zh',  'З' => 'Z',   'И' => 'I',   
        'Й' => 'Y',   'К' => 'K',   'Л' => 'L',   
        'М' => 'M',   'Н' => 'N',   'О' => 'O',   
        'П' => 'P',   'Р' => 'R',   'С' => 'S',   
        'Т' => 'T',   'У' => 'U',   'Ф' => 'F',
        'Х' => 'H',   'Ц' => 'Ts',  'Ч' => 'Ch',
        'Ш' => 'Sh',  'Щ' => 'Sht', 'Ь' => '',
        'Ъ' => 'A',   'Ю' => 'Yu',  'Я' => 'Ya',

        'ия' => 'ia', 'ИЯ' => 'IA' // add this!
        );  
        $c = reset($c); // we just need the first element of that array
        return isset($converter[$c]) ? $converter[$c] : $c;
    }, $string);
}
```

Comment: Just spotted a small problem, though. When the text is all caps, the conversion doesn't work properly. I tried adding the capitalised version of the combination ('ИЯ' => 'IA') but words written in all caps and having "ИЯ" are converted to "IYA".

Comment: You need to add this in the regular expression as well, by making it case insensitive: add the `i` modifier. I updated the answer accordingly. I also added the `s` modifier to support mutliline input.